# what is ViewModelFactory

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mvvm, android-viewmodel

what is viewModelFactory and when and why should I use it I am new to android and actually I can't understand these concepts in MVVM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ViewModelProviders` and `ViewModelProviders.Factory` are used to ensure that only one instance of the `viewModel` is created across the configuration changes in an activity or if the activity is recreated. Also there is a callback `onCleared()` available in viewModel if you create the custom viewModel by extending `ViewModel` class in architecture components. This callback method is called when the activity is destroyed. So you can clear any instances you used in the viewModel. But for the proper working of this callback, the viewModel should be creates with `ViewModelProviders` and `ViewModelProviders.Factory`.

Comment: Can we have a generic ViewModelFactory class for all the ViewModels in an App ? And can we make the ViewModelFactory class as singleton ?